# MongoDB: how to $lookup a field in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to retrieve some lookup data for an embedded array in a document. Here is a sample of the data:

```
[
   {
      "_id": "58a4fa0e24180825b05e14e9",
      "user_id": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13",
      "user": {
         "firstname": "John",
         "lastname": "Doe"
      },
      "stages": [
         {
            "user_id": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13"
         },
         {
            "user_id": "589cf6511b94281f346343c3"
         }
      ],
   }
]
```

As you see, `stages` is an array, containing `user_id` fields only. These are pointing to the `_id` field in another collection called `users`.

Here is how I got the above result:

```
db.collection('things').aggregate([{
        $match: finder
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'user_id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'user'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$user'
    }
]);
```

Now, this is pretty straightforward: a selection of records, with the `user` field looked up with `$lookup`. But how can I do the same with the elements of `stages`? The desired result would be this:

```
[
   {
      "_id": "58a4fa0e24180825b05e14e9",
      "user_id": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13",
      "user": {
         "firstname": "John",
         "lastname": "Doe"
      },

      "stages": [
         {
            "user_id": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13",
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe"
         },
         {
            "user_id": "589cf6511b94281f346343c3"
            "firstname": "Jane",
            "lastname": "Doe"
         }
      ],
   }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you're missing is an unwind in the stages and a group call after it. I tested the following code and got similar result:

```
db.collection('things').aggregate([
               { $match: finder },
               { $lookup: {  from: 'users',
                             localField: 'user_id',
                              foreignField: '_id',
                              as: 'user'
                           }
               },
               { $unwind: '$stages' },
               {$lookup : {from : 'users', localField: 'stages.user_id', foreignField: '_id', as : 'stages'}},
               {$group : { _id: '$_id', userId: "$userId",..., stages: {$push : "$stages"}}}
               ]);
```

Hope my code was useful

Comment: It now says: "The field user_id must be an accumulator object".

Comment: My bad, please put a $ before the fields you want to extract. Like {_id: '$_id', userId: "$user_id"...

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135823/discussion-between-tamas-polgar-and-israel-zinc).